# kotlin command returns ClassNotFoundException

Tags: kotlin

I tried to run `kotlin` and I got this error.

[image]

I have installed `kotlinc`

[image]

And put `kotlinc\bin` in the Path Variables

[image]

Comment: try `cd "C:\Program Files\kotlinc\bin"` then run `.\kotlin`

Comment: it returns the same error @RickyMo

Comment: but kotlin works well in IntelliJ Idea (can build and run)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to uninstall kotlin and then installed it again. And it solved my problem.